# spark multiplie value of frequence in an other string column dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with this shema:

```
ocId: integer (nullable = true).
freq: integer (nullable = true).
nameFile: string (nullable = true)
word: string (nullable = true).
```

I want to multiplie value of row freq in column word to have word*freq in         a new column

example :

1. value freq = 2, word =  analyses ---->a new column : analyses,analyses.
2. value freq = 3, word =  carried ---->a new column
   :        carried,carried,carried.
3. value freq = 1, word = 
   atlantic---->a new column : atlantic.
4. value freq = 2, word = 
   hello---->a new column : hello,hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a UDF similar to the following:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 2, "a", "analyses"),
  (2, 3, "b", "carried"),
  (3, 1, "c", "atlantic"),
  (4, 2, "d", "hello"),
  (5, 2, "e", ""),
  (6, 1, "f", null),
  (7, 0, "f", "blah")
).toDF("ocId", "freq", "nameFile", "word")

def multiWords = udf(
  (word: String, freq: Int) => word match {
     case null => null
     case "" => ""
     case _ => if (freq > 0) ((word + ",") * freq).dropRight(1) + "."
               else ""
  }
)

df.withColumn("multiWords", multiWords($"word", $"freq")).
  show(false)

// +----+----+--------+--------+------------------------+
// |ocId|freq|nameFile|word    |multiWords              |
// +----+----+--------+--------+------------------------+
// |1   |2   |a       |analyses|analyses,analyses.      |
// |2   |3   |b       |carried |carried,carried,carried.|
// |3   |1   |c       |atlantic|atlantic.               |
// |4   |2   |d       |hello   |hello,hello.            |
// |5   |2   |e       |        |                        |
// |6   |1   |f       |null    |null                    |
// |7   |0   |g       |blah    |                        |
// +----+----+--------+--------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I tested , it 's work without problem                                                                    Thank you very much